# Openpyxl. Ignoring cells that have style but have no values

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm wondering is there a way to make openpyxl to ignore cells without a values?  Cells are in xml tree, but have no values, only styles defined

The problem is, I have a sheet, which xml structure is like this:

```
<row r="18" spans="3:9 16384:16384" ht="15" customHeight="1" thickBot="1">
    <c r="C18" s="14" t="s">
        <v>24</v>
    </c>
    <c r="D18" s="14" t="s">
        <v>25</v>
    </c>
    <c r="E18" s="14" t="s">
        <v>27</v>
    </c>
    ...
    <c r="I18" s="12"/>
    <c r="XFD18" s="13"/>
</row>
<row r="1048576" spans="4:4" ht="15" customHeight="1">
    <c r="D1048576" s="13"/>
</row>
```

When `openpyxl` gets to the row 18 and tries to get cells, the way it generates cells make it to fill the gap between cells I18 and XFD18 with 16336 Empty cells. And same goes for rows 18 - 1048576, I'm getting a million of empty rows because of the way rows in XML tree are being parsed in `ws.iter_rows` method. I see logic beihind it and I understand that it's a problem of xlsx file itself, but I want to know whether it's something I can deal with by using openpyxl API?

I know that `xlrd` ignores empty cells formatting (it's just not implemented) and thus `xlrd` won't add such cells to the row. Is there a way to make openpyxl act the same? Looking at source code, I see no way of doing that using existing API, except from defining `max_column` and `max_row` for `ws.iter_rows` method (which is not optimal, since actual number of columns/rows may vary)

I managed to accomplish the task modifying the `xml_source` like that (wb is opened as read_only):

```py
import io
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

from openpyxl.xml.functions import iterparse, safe_iterator
from openpyxl.xml.constants import SHEET_MAIN_NS


ROW_TAG = '{%s}row' % SHEET_MAIN_NS
CELL_TAG = '{%s}c' % SHEET_MAIN_NS
VALUE_TAG = '{%s}v' % SHEET_MAIN_NS
SHEET_DATA = '{%s}sheetData' % SHEET_MAIN_NS

def clean_up_xml_from_empty_rows_and_cells(sheet):
    sheet_data = None

    rows_to_delete = set()
    p = iterparse(sheet.xml_source, tag=[ROW_TAG], remove_blank_text=True)
    for _event, element in p:

        if element.tag == SHEET_DATA:
            sheet_data = element
            continue

        if element.tag == ROW_TAG:
            cells_to_delete = set()
            for cell in safe_iterator(element, CELL_TAG):
                if cell.findtext(VALUE_TAG) is None:
                    cells_to_delete.add(cell)

            for cell in cells_to_delete:
                element.remove(cell)

            if not len(element):
                rows_to_delete.add(element)

    for row in rows_to_delete:
        sheet_data.remove(row)

    out_file = io.BytesIO()

    element_tree = ET.ElementTree(p.root)
    element_tree.write(out_file, encoding='utf8')
    out_file.seek(0)

    sheet.xml_source = out_file
```

But it feels so wrong! And so dangerous, I'm absolutely unsure the function like that won't break the parsing of other xlsx files.

Is there really no way to ignore cells without a values? Browsing SO and google - it feels like noone ever encountered such problems :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably best off patching `parse_row()` which is where this stuff is controlled. This is easier to work with and thest than messing with the parser.

Comment: If only we were using python3 and openpyxl 3.1 :(

it's python2.7 and openpyxl 2.5.14. Should've mentioned, sorry

Comment: You should be able to use openpyxl 2.6 which has the same code as 3.0.

Comment: Interesting, I did a research and found out we actually downgraded 2.6.4 to 2.5.14 because of this issue:
https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1321
PR was merged only to 3.0
It seems it should've been merged in 2.6.x also?

Comment: There will be no more releases for the 2.6 series.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. I asked just because of the fact that other 1 yo old issues are based on 2.6 branch and I thought PR from issue should've also been merged into 2.6 branch at it's time (Might be wrong though, you know better ;) )
I will locally patch 2.6.4 for the mentioned issue and also patch `parse_row` method. Thanks for the help! Highly appreciated.

Comment: Anyone running Python 2.7 in production should **not** expect any support.

Comment: Should not expect any support from whom? Any support from python devs in a form of patches and updates? I agree. (although there are almight redhat and it's python2 extended support) Support from community? I strongly disagree. :^) Some project can't be ported to recent versions on a whim

Comment: Python 2.7's EOL was communicated long enough ago not to be considered EOL. The same goes for many libraries including openpyxl, though you are free to fork and backport.